# How to make a timer app that could run even when the app is in the background mode

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have a simple timer app and I need it to work and send sound signals when using other system apps like iBooks. But when I press the Home button and the app goes in the background mode it seems to pause. The timer and sounds resume when I bring the View Controller back. What is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: App can't run in the background unless they are either VOIP, AudioStreamer, LocationBased or accessory apps. The use of timers is not possible in the background. You best option it to schedule a location notification and not use times. If your app is running you can handle the local notification. If you app is running in the background the user will be pressented with the notification.

Comment: I misused the term. I need it to run and send signals when using other apps like iBooks.

Comment: First you will not be able to detect if any other app is started since this is a breach of privacy. Apple will not allow it if you are going to deploy your app via the AppStore.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant. Many apps are made like this. You can be running using a running app and listening to iTunes music or reading from iBooks if you read and run.

Comment: You mean you want your app to run in the background, this is possible if your app is either a VOIP client, audio player, location based or accessory app.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Which is a standard running app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130774/discussion-between-anton-platonov-and-rckoenes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is an accessory app you need to add the background mode accessory.

You can do this from the capabilities tab in your target.
If you do use this option and Apple finds that you are not commincateing with a external accessory your app will be rejected.

[image: External accessory communication option ins capabilities]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at **UILocalNotification** (UNNotificationRequest if your targeting iOS 10 only).

When your app is running, you simply register a UILocalNotification to fire at a set date and time. This will then still fire when your app is in the foreground, backgrounded or removed from multitasking entirely.

Check out the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification